# override OnStartup in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, startup

For some reason I can't get this to work at all.  I have read from various sources that I can override OnStartup in a WPF application and it will fire off as the App is created.  However, no matter what I do, nothing is happening.  Here is the code.

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      // My code goes here, but nothing ever happens.

      base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Obviously I am missing something.  Sadly the MSDN page doesn't offer much insight either.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup.aspx

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
It turns out that my problem was a small typo in the namespace.  App.xaml.cs had the class defined as 'RTDMyApp.App' and the App.xaml file was referring to it as 'RTD_MYApp.App'  At any rate, this fact, combined with the accepted answer below has gotten me back on track.

Comment: if you start your with VS with the "step into" command, what happens ?

Comment: Try having your code after the base.OnStartup(e);

Comment: Does the app start ok (except your code isnt run) or do you get an exception? also, have you tried explicitly regertering on the Startup event in app.xaml?

Comment: I've tried with a quick WPF project in VS 2010 and I can override OnStartup just fine.
If you post both the App.xaml and the App.xaml.cs files from your project I may be able to help you.

Comment: @aL3891, yes, the app starts up fine.  It just goes straight to whatever is defined in 'StartupUI'

Comment: @Ingo - Don't want to sound like a jerk, but that is a silly idea.

Comment: @Ingo: If OnStartup is never called, how should this change anything?

Comment: @A.R. Hehe might be, but I thought that perhaps some objects had to be initialized before you could do certain things.

Comment: @AR: it will definitely work but perhaps you have forgotten to set your Start up Uri set it on xaml or in Startup method and see is it working or not...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you really want to do is to **subscribe** to the `Startup` event. You can do this in your XAML file:

```
<Application ... Startup="Application_Startup">
```

Comment: Hmm... I think something is really wrong here.  If I do this on a "fresh" application, everything is great.  On the other hand, my current app will no longer compile, telling me that it can't find 'Application_Startup' even though it is clearly defined.

Comment: Handling the event is different from overriding the virtual method

Comment: @Erno: I know that handling an event is different from overriding a virtual method. But in this specific case? What really **is** the difference?

Comment: There might be some problem with the app.xaml not having x:Class beeing set to the right value, can you post you app.xaml?

Comment: @A.R. Do the class name in your xaml.cs file match the name in `x:Class` in the xaml file?

Comment: I added the `OnStartup` method shown in the question to my `App` class and it was executed without modifying anything else.

Answer (score 24):

Did you remove the StartupUri too from the App xaml?

If you did you have to create the window you want show:

```
base.OnStartUp(e);
var window = new Window1();
this.MainWindow = window;
window.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question was asked and answered about 12 years ago now, but I had a similar lack of understanding of the startup process, which the existing responses didn't adequately explain for me. As I understand it better now, I thought I'd add my explanation.

In your App.xaml file you have 3 options for influencing the startup sequence (normally, you'd only want to do ONE of these):

1. Add 'StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml' - This specifies the XAML file of your MainWindow, which will automatically be instantiated and shown, or
2. Add 'Startup="*YourCustomStartupHandler*"' - This specifies an event handler that you've defined in App.xaml.cs that handles the 'Startup' Event. 
   Note: **DON'T call base.OnStartup()** from here, as it will raise a new Startup Event which triggers your custom startup handler again -> infinite loop/StackOverflow !!!
3. Don't add anything to the App XAML, instead override the base OnStartup(e) method of the base Application class in your App code. 
   WPF automatically calls the Application.OnStartup() function when your App runs. If you override it, then your code gets executed instead. Your OnStartup() override function should call the base OnStartup() function before exiting, as the base method raises the 'Startup' Event (which your code, or potentially some framework you're using might depend on)

If you choose to do both #2 (define Startup event handler) and #3 (override base OnStartup() method) then BOTH those routines will be called (assuming your override function calls the base OnStartup() method before exiting)

In either method 2 or 3, you'd manually instantiate a MainWindow object in the function you've written, and call it's .Show() method to display it.

Answer (score -2):

Sequence sequence sequence. How annoying.

The right sequence (for a WPF application with **NO Main method** explicitly developed/declared) is:

```
// XAML
...       Startup="Application_Startup"

//code-behind
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
 ...
 ...
 // do something.  In fact, here I do a lot of stuff that reflects 
 // some serious recent application illnesss:
try
        {
              //http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/618027/uriformatexception-thrown-by-ms-internal-fontcache-util
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("windir", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"));

            // per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.ietflanguagetag(v=vs.110).aspx

            var cultureName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(FrameworkElement),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(cultureName)));


            // Setup unhandled exception handlers
            #region Handlers For Unhandled Exceptions
            // anything else to do on startup can go here and will fire after the base startup event of the application
            // First make sure anything after this is handled
            // Creates an instance of the class holding delegate methods that will handle unhandled exceptions.
            CustomExceptionHandler eh = new CustomExceptionHandler();

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(eh.OnAppDomainException);

            // this ensures that any unhandled exceptions bubble up to a messagebox at least
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(eh.OnDispatcherUnhandledException);

            #endregion  Handlers For Unhandled Exceptions


            // Start the dispatcher
            // for Galasoft threading and messaging

            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.PreserveExceptionDetail();
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

and then I do:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
        App.HasRaisedFatalException = false;

        base.OnStartup(e);

        try
        {



            //Force just one copy to run
            this.ForceSingleInstance();

...
...
...
}
```

and so far the patient is feeling much better.