# WPF Application ignoring AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5, connection-string, localdb

I have a solution (All .NET 4.5 projects) which has a windows service, a WPF UI application and a data layer in which I have my EDMX model and a generic repository.

When I debug the service, data ends up in the database and I want to UI to use the same database file when I launch it.

So I created a directory like such:

```
[solution root directory]\Data
```

In which I put the MDF and LDF in. I made sure my EDMX model uses this MDF file when I do updates and such.

For the service and the UI to use the same MDF file, I made sure their connection string use the `|DataDirectory|` symbol and do this when they both start:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    string dataDir = Utilities.Utilities.ReturnDataDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dataDir);
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}
```

Here's the code for `ReturnDataDirectory`:

```
public static string ReturnDataDirectory(Assembly referingAssembly)
{
    string curDir = referingAssembly.Location;
    string dataDir = string.Empty;
    int x;
    var curDirArray = curDir.Split('\\');

    //Return a directory without the 'Solution.Name\bin\Debug' part...
    for (x = 0; x < (curDirArray.Count() - 4);x++ )
    {
        dataDir += string.Format("{0}\\", curDirArray[x]);
    }

    return string.Format("{0}Data", dataDir);
}
```

This generates the exact directory where the MDF file indeed resides so the problem is not there, AFAIK.

Yet, when I start the WPF UI, I get this error:

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\\Dropbox\\My Docs\\MySolution\\MySolution.UI\\bin\\Debug\\MySolution.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

Why on earth is it still trying to look there after setting `|DataDirectory|` correctly ? There is no MDF file there anyways, and that's how I intend it for the moment being.

Here is the connection string used in the app.config of the WPF UI ap:

```
<add name="MySolutionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MySolution.csdl|res://*/MySolution.ssdl|res://*/MySolution.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MySolution.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What am I missing ?

Thank you!

**EDIT**: This approach works for the Windows Service project, but not for the WPF UI application. Is it because I'm setting the `|DataDirectory|` too late ? I also tried sniffing something use Process Monitor, and I can't pickup the UI application trying to access an MDF whatsoever :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my hunch was correct. In the WPF UI application, I was setting `|DataDirectory|` too late in the process.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306549/override-onstartup-in-wpf) solved the problem.