# c# WPF how to delay autostart of an application?

Tags: c#, wpf

My question is how can i delay the autostart on user logon in an WPF Project. Because its necessary on this application.

I tried:

```
void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        base.OnStartup(e);

    }
```

but it seems like the OnStartup method isnt aviable. Its always an error. So there is something i dont get.

Comment: ...  logon in an WPF Project .. <- what does it mean ?

Comment: what kind of delay? As in show window after a delay? or pause processing?

Comment: i mean when the user logs in the application starts and tries to acces a database. But sometimes the database is to slow. And so i need to delay the autostart of the programm. Like it starts 10 seconds after all other programms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306549/override-onstartup-in-wpf) might have what you're looking for:

> I think what you really want to do is to subscribe to the Startup
>   event. You can do this in your XAML file

[Click here to get started with WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 2):

You can always just use

```
public App()
   {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
   }
```

on the App.xaml.cs

Of as already mentioned you need to subscribe to the OnStartup event on xaml.